# jQuery toggle multiple menu items (close any open and open a new)

Tags: jquery

Sorry if the title sounds vague, but I really don't know how to word this one.

I've got a menu containing 6 items. I want to assign each menu item to open up it's own corresponding div block above the menu, in a certain position.

I've managed to do this, and it works really nicely, however the divs will only close if I click on the same menu item to close it.

If I try to open one div, and then click on another menu item the old one remains open and the new one opens.

Can I set them up as a group so that if I click on a new menu item, it closes any currently open divs?

I've been trying for the past 20 minutes to paste my code but this editor doesn't accept all of it as code, and it's definitely not incorrect.

I've put it on here...

http://jsfiddle.net/AFpYc/

```
$('.divs').hide();
$('.links').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href')).toggle('fade');
});
```

Comment: *"I've been trying for the past 20 minutes to paste my code"* Did you see you have some help linked from the edit toolbar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `.siblings()`. The `.siblings()` method allows us to search through the siblings of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Css

```
.activeClass
{
    color:RED;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.divs').hide();
    $('.links').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var targetDiv = $($(this).attr('href'));

        $('.links').removeClass("activeClass");
        if(targetDiv.css("display") == "none")
        {
            $(this).addClass("activeClass");
        }

        targetDiv.siblings().hide(); 
        // hide those elements immediately, you would change to fadeOut if you like
        targetDiv.toggle('fade');
    });

    $(document).click(function(e)
    {
        if($(e.target).hasClass("links") || $("#popup_canvas").find(e.target).length > 0)
        {
            // exclude the links and div that pops
        }
        else
        {
            $('.divs').hide();
            $('.links').removeClass("activeClass");
        }
    });
})
```

Updated and please find code example at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AFpYc/8/

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm looking for, but for one extra bit, can I add a function to that that tells the links I initially clicked to change the A state to 'active' whilst that div is showing?

Comment: And also maybe a way to set any click outside of the opened div, to close it? I should have put all these in my original question, sorry!

Comment: Of coz, you can do it. Let me modify it.

Comment: As my understanding, the state 'active' of link is managed by the browser, it seems not possible to change the state by javascript. I'm guessing you would like to the look of the link, I have added a class to the link that clicked. You would use `activeClass` for styling the link.

Comment: Hmm but now that doesn't open the divs when clicked, because the whole class has changed

Comment: Also, I can't turn off any of the links now, they just stay on 'active' class.

Comment: Which 'class' do you mean? I have modified it in jsfiddle, check it. http://jsfiddle.net/AFpYc/5/

Comment: It works really nicely, especially with the click off thing, but what I mean is when a link is clicked, the div shows and the link is displayed as 'active', but then when clicked again, the div disappears but the link stays on the activeClass class.

Comment: Actually don't worry, this will do just fine. Thank you very much for helping me out Derek! :)

Comment: ACtually, that works in JSfiddle but now doesn't work on my site.. not sure why either. From the looks of the code, the links just apply the 'links' class.

Comment: Ah actually, the divs only show when double clicking ont he links

Comment: And the classes don't change to activeClass. would it be helpful if you could see it?

Comment: Please email me at lcollings@asg.co.uk - I have uploaded site and I think I know why I'm not seeing anything. The jscript is always making the display:none of the divs

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from toggle... Toggle is a on/off switch. Which means it it opens closed things and closes opened things.

I suggest you change toggle for `.show()` and `.hide()`... this way you can easily do what you want, if a click needs to open up a div, then `.show()` is better suited. You can then decide to `.hide()` all the other divs before opening it. I have made the fiddle work.

http://jsfiddle.net/AFpYc/2/

Note how I get all the divs that we want to close but the one that we will open, and open it.

```
$('.divs').hide();
$('.links').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#popup_canvas').children('div').not($(this).attr('href')).hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show('fade');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$('.divs').hide();
$('.links').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href')).toggle('fade');
    $($(this).attr('href')).siblings().fadeOut()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AFpYc/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
$('.divs').hide();
$('.links').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.divs').fadeOut('slow');
    $($(this).attr('href')+':hidden').fadeIn('slow');    
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/6brww/)

Comment: I like this, and I've tried editing it but I can't seem to close it by clicking on the same link now, it just disappears and then re-opens.

Comment: @LeeCollings Do you prefer the new one ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more sophisticated version... the active element is kept track of using the css class active and any active elements are faded out before the new one is faded in.

http://jsfiddle.net/TrRD9/

```
$('.divs').hide();
$('.links').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var $href = $($(this).attr('href')); // get target element

    if($href.is('.active')) // if its already active, ignore it
        return;

    // get any active sibling elements
    var $activeSiblings = $href.siblings('.active');
    if($activeSiblings.length > 0)
    {
        // fade out active siblings first
        $activeSiblings.removeClass('active').fadeOut(function(){
            $href.addClass('active').fadeIn();
        });
    } else {
        //  no siblings are active
        $href.addClass('active').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked out the jsFiddle? It's right there, working.

Answer (score 0):

use .not to filter all items from the current one

```
var $alldivs = $('.divs').hide();
$('.links').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var $current = $(href);
    $current.show(500);
    $alldivs.not($current).hide(500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AFpYc/6/

Comment: and an optimised version, without any "id", using $.index and $.eq, http://jsfiddle.net/AFpYc/7/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple but effective version if you're actually showing and hiding your menus (as opposed to adding and removing classes).  I'm using "not(thismenu)" to make sure only the other menus are hidden when a new menu is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

<!--**************************************************************************************-->
<!--*** Bind menubar items
<!--**************************************************************************************-->

  $(".menubaritem").click(function(e){
    var thismenu = $(this).find('.menubaroptions');
    $('.menubaroptions').not(thismenu).slideUp("fast"); // hiding all other menus
    thismenu.slideDown("fast");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

<!--**************************************************************************************-->
<!--*** Bind menubar menu options (to hide current menu when option is clicked)
<!--**************************************************************************************-->

  $(".menubaroption").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest(".menubaroptions").slideUp("fast");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

<!--**************************************************************************************-->
<!--*** Bind slideup to all menus on body click
<!--**************************************************************************************-->

  $("body").click(function (e) { // binding onclick to body
    $(".menubaroptions").slideUp("fast"); // hiding all menus
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

Where the HTML would look something like this for each menubar item:

```
  <td class='menubaritem clickable'>Menu Item<div class=menubararrow></div>
    <div style='position:absolute;right:1px'>
      <div class=menubaroptions>
        include("menu-blah.php");
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
```

And just for the sake of completion, here is the css

```
.menubaritem{height:26px;color:white;font-weight:normal;padding:2px 20px 2px 10px;white-space:nowrap;text-align:right;position:relative}
.menubaritem:hover{background-color:#404040;color:yellow}
.menubararrow{position:absolute;display:inline;margin-left:10px;float:right;margin-top:4px;border-left: 5px solid transparent;border-right: 5px solid transparent;border-top: 5px solid ".$primarytextcolour.}
.menubaritem:hover div.menubararrow{border-top: 5px solid white;}

.menubaroptions{border:1px solid white;display:none;position:relative;top:4px;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.80);color:white;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #888888;border-radius:4px;z-index:100}
.menubaroptions td{background-color:transparent;color: white;padding: 4px 10px;border:none;border-top:1px solid transparent;border-bottom:1px solid transparent}
.menubaroptions td.menubaroption:hover{background-color:grey;color:white;opacity:1;border-top:1px solid transparent;border-bottom:1px solid transparent}
.clickable{cursor:hand;cursor:pointer;pointer:hand;}
```